How do you refresh Temporary AWS Credentials in a Spring Boot Java app?
we are currently sending/receiving messages from SQS queues. Loading credentials from the .aws/credentials file which provides access_key, secret_access_key, session_token. After a few hours the credentials expire, so I am wondering how to refresh those without having to manually intervene.
AWS SQS Config:
@Configuration
public class AwsSqsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.sqs.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.credentials.profile.name}")
    String profileName;

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return ProfileCredentialsProvider
                .builder()
                .profileName(profileName)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) throws URISyntaxException {
        return SqsAsyncClient.builder()
            .endpointOverride(new URI(endpoint))
            .region(Region.of(region))
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SqsTemplate sqsTemplate(SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient) {
        return SqsTemplate.builder().sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient).build();
    }

}


SQS Message Listener:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SQSMessageListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSMessageListener.class);

    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;

    private SqsTemplate sqsTemplate;

    @SqsListener("check-event-status")
    public void receiveCheckEventStatusMessage(String message) {
        log.trace("Received check event status message: {}", message);

        // Logic below...
    }

    @SqsListener("update-service")
    public void receiveUpdateServiceMessage(String message) {
        log.trace("Received update service message: {}", message);

        // Logic below...
    }

    @SqsListener("creation")
    public void receiveCreationMessage(String message) {
        log.trace("Received creation message: {}", message);

        // Logic below...
    }

    @SqsListener("execution")
    public void receiveExecutionMessage(String message) {
        log.trace("Received execution message: {}", message);

        // Logic below...
    }

}


Creation Task:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreationTask implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreationTask.class);

    private SqsTemplate sqsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.trace("Running CreationTask");

        log.trace("Sending payload-1");
        String payload1 = Status.SCHEDULED.name() + ":1";
        sqsTemplate.send(sqsSendOptions -> sqsSendOptions.queue("execution").payload(payload1));

        log.trace("Sending payload-2");
        String payload2 = Status.INPROGRESS.name() + ":2";
        sqsTemplate.send(sqsSendOptions -> sqsSendOptions.queue("execution").payload(payload2));

        log.trace("Sending payload-3");
        String payload3 = Status.CLOSED.name() + ":3";
        sqsTemplate.send(sqsSendOptions -> sqsSendOptions.queue("execution").payload(payload3));
    }

}



hot reload properties is a popular question and has been answered here - but like the answer correctly explains reloading properties, while possible doesn't solve your problems, since the beans which use these properties are most likely already instantiated. So you need to update those attributes in those beans which is not always trivial. Shouldn't you rather try to get credentials which live longer?

@JAsgarov I'll have to check if longer living creds are an option but I'm guessing there is a limit somewhere and permanent creds seems like a bad idea from a security point. I'm open to other solutions as well if it opens up possibilities, it doesn't have to stick to using the aws creds file, I know there are lots of other AWS credential providers so if one of those have options I'd love to know.

@TomDelebo Are you running on an ec2 instance? Can you use instance roles or ecs task roles to handle the credentials for you. If you're running in that fashion then it should hot reload it and take care of the fixing.
If you're doing sso credentials as a user then I have no idea on what you should do here.

To automatically refresh your AWS credentials without manual intervention, you can use the AWS Security Token Service (STS) to assume a role that provides temporary security credentials. Here’s a general approach:
• Create an IAM Role: Ensure you have an IAM role with the necessary permissions to access your SQS queues.
• Use AWS STS to Assume the Role: Use the AssumeRole API to obtain temporary security credentials. These credentials include an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token.
• Automate Credential Refresh: Implement a script or use a library to periodically refresh these credentials before they expire. You can use the AWS SDK for your preferred programming language to handle this.
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsSessionCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.SqsAsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.StsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleResponse;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AwsSqsConfig {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.sqs.endpoint}")
    private String endpoint;

    @Value("${aws.role.arn}")
    private String roleArn;

    @Value("${aws.role.session.name}")
    private String roleSessionName;

    private AwsSessionCredentials sessionCredentials;

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        refreshCredentials();
        return StaticCredentialsProvider.create(sessionCredentials);
    }

    @Bean
    public SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) throws URISyntaxException {
        return SqsAsyncClient.builder()
                .endpointOverride(new URI(endpoint))
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000) // Refresh every hour
    public void refreshCredentials() {
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder().region(Region.of(region)).build();
        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(roleArn)
                .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
                .build();

        AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
        sessionCredentials = AwsSessionCredentials.create(
                roleResponse.credentials().accessKeyId(),
                roleResponse.credentials().secretAccessKey(),
                roleResponse.credentials().sessionToken()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public SqsTemplate sqsTemplate(SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient) {
        return SqsTemplate.builder().sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient).build();
    }
}


You should probably increase the refresh rate to be shorter than the credential expiry that way you can retry before the creds expire.
